# Using TailwindCSS - how to activate the "odd" variant for flex properties in an each loop

Tags: css, css-selectors, tailwind-css, svelte

I would like to be able to "flip" the order of some elements on every odd indexed element in an each loop.

The output should be:

```
<div class="flex flex-row"/>
<div class="flex flex-row-reverse"/>
<div class="flex flex-row"/>
<div class="flex flex-row-reverse"/>
```

...and so on.

So I want to do something like:

```
{#each elems as elem}
<div class="flex flex-row odd:flex-row-reverse"/>
{/each}
```

Currently my tailwind.config.js includes:

```
variants: {
    extend: {
        flexDirection: ['odd']
    }
},
```

but this has no effect in the following element:

```
<div class="flex flex-row odd:flex-row-reverse">
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved doing the following:

```
{#each elems as elem, i}
    <div class="flex {i % 2 ? 'flex-row' : 'flow-row-reverse'}" />
{/each}
```

Not sure if Tailwind has a helper for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working as intended: [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-minimal-tailwind-9k42nh?file=src%2Froutes%2Findex.svelte)

Note that with Tailwind 3.0 and beyond, you should *remove* variants configuration, as they are all available for every utility by default (see [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#remove-variant-configuration)).

The `<div class="flex flex-row odd:flex-row-reverse">` output is normal and expected. Tailwind will **not** preprocess your code into `<div class="flex flex-row">` on even rows and `<div class="flex flex-row-reverse">` on odd rows. Instead, it will create and use the following rule:

```css
.odd\:flex-row-reverse:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

which will then override the default `flex-row` class for odd-numbered children.